# Get the longest word from sentence algorithm problem with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am building an algorithm of my own that is supposed to return the longest word from a sentence with javascript. The custom algorithm is compiling but returning an incorrect string. Am trying to solve programming problems without plagiarising so please help....

***logic***

**a)** Form an array out of the sentence using `.split(" ")` function.

**b)** Define a variable `index` that will be used to store the index of the element with the largest length

**c)** Define a default string `mystring` that we will use for comparisons in the loop

**d)** Iterate through the array we formed in step while comparing each string at each index with our variable `mystring`, if the string at the specified position is larger than our `mystring`,we get the index of that string and store it in the `index` variable..

**e)** We return the string at the `index` of the array that we got from the loop

***Expectations***

For a sample sentence like `I love the United States of America`,the algorithm should return `America` as the longest string. Instead its returning `United` which is false.
The rest of the problem is commented in my code below

**Code**

```js
function longestWord(sentence) {
  //we use this index to store the index of the 
  //longest word in the array
  let index = 0;
  //define an empty string for comparison
  let mystring = "";
  //define a new array
  let arr = sentence.split(" ");
  //iterate through the array
  for (let p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
    if (arr[p].length > mystring.length) {
      //get the index and store in the variable
      index = p;

    }
  }
  //return the element at the index we got
  return arr[index];
}
console.log(longestWord("I love the United States of America"));
//function returns United, please help
```

Comment: You're never setting `mystring` in your for loop, and therefore the code you posted simply returns the last word. It's also the longest, which means your code accidentally gets it right. But it also means it doesn't return `"United"`... I have no clue why you're getting a random word in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: You can use `.split(' ')` instead of `.split(" ")` because its just one char, but ot wouldn't fix your problem

Comment: but the conditional structure should filter and make sure only strings... Wait a minute, i got what you meant, thank you so much man :))

Comment: @Chris g, iadded `mystring=arr[i];`, and its working fine now thank you

Comment: Ok, great, but how did you get `United`...?

Comment: i had  a similar string but wirth different wors, i assumed it will return the same index as an earlier sentence i had tried, sorry

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to change the mystring variable valut to the new string value.

try this :

```
      function longestWord(sentence) {
       //we use this index to store the index of the 
       //longest word in the array
       let index = 0;
       //define an empty string for comparison
       let mystring = "";
       //define a new array
      let arr = sentence.split(" ");
      //iterate through the array
      for (let p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
      if (arr[p].length > mystring.length) {
        //get the index and store in the variable
        index = p;
        mystring=arr[index];

      }
   }
     //return the element at the index we got
     return arr[index];
  }
  console.log(longestWord("I love the United States of America"));
```